Windows Event Viewer not Logging more than a day log - Application Logs
Application log is not retaining more than a day worth of logs. I have SQL Server 2019 installed and other DW application. I tried to restart the Windows event log service and also the server as well. But nothing seems to change. What is actually going on? I can see Security, Setup & System logs however just Application Log is not returning.

Please check the Event Log Policies on your computer to see if one is causing the problem. Some application may be spamming the log and causing some policy to trigger.

Have you looked at https://helpcenter.netwrix.com/bundle/Auditor_10.0/page/Content/Configure_IT_Infrastructure/Windows_Server/WS_Event_Log_Settings.htm?

Thank you all. The info was very informative. I resolved this by setting the -m parameter in SQL Sever config. I also added the -e paramater to capture error logs. That solved it.
